# How do you create an admin page in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, admin, react-admin

I was wondering if there was a way to create an administration page that can then be used to publish content on a website. This administration page would be used by those who do not understand coding to add news articles or update research information. I was looking at React-admin which uses Material Design, but their admin pages seem more focused on user data and design elements, not contributing content.

Would react-admin still be the best to use or is there an easy way to create this elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly create something like this with React as the frontend. You will also need some kind of backend which stores the content submitted by users. This task is just like any other software engineering task where you need to gather requirements for the system and design it. Going into these details is too much for the format of Stack Oveflow, though.

Comment: Do you mean using something such as a SQL database which would update based on the state of the React component that was updated via the administrator?

Comment: gatsby + word press ?

Comment: React Admin contributor here. React Admin is just an admin interface you can plug over a REST API.
It is not a CMS by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a simple CMS using React + Firebase. I came across an article, which exactly fits in to your requirements.

https://hackernoon.com/how-i-built-a-content-management-system-for-a-react-app-in-one-day-269df17f5509

Comment: Thank you, Dinesh. The only thing I worry about with that is the security of the information in Firebase.